# Error sending Firebase message with Arduino

Tags: firebase, arduino, firebase-cloud-messaging, esp8266

I'm trying to run the firebase messaging sketch from the main library here using nodeMCU: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino

It connects to wifi but keeps giving me the number 1 connection refused error when trying to connect to Firebase server. I've gotten the individual token from my Android app using the get token instance ID method and logged it to the console on Android Studio and have successfully sent a message to myself through the standard Firebase console using this token, so the token is correct I assume. I entered the token in the define CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID.

[image: PHOTO OF TOKEN IN CONSOLE AND METHOD USED]

So I have entered the token along with the server key from the locations highlighted by the arrows in the below photo into the sketch, but not getting any success with the connection.

here's the blank original sketch:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseCloudMessaging.h>

// Set these to run example.
#define WIFI_SSID "SSID"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "PASSWORD"

#define SERVER_KEY "key_from_dashboard"
#define CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID "key_from_client_after_registration"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // connect to wifi.
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connected: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  FirebaseCloudMessaging fcm(SERVER_KEY);
  FirebaseCloudMessage message =
    FirebaseCloudMessage::SimpleNotification("Hello World!", "What's happening?");
  FirebaseError error = fcm.SendMessageToUser(CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID, message);
  if (error) {
    Serial.print("Error:");
    Serial.print(error.code());
    Serial.print(" :: ");
    Serial.println(error.message().c_str());
  } else {
    Serial.println("Sent OK!");
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

For the server key variable I've tried to use the fields highlighted by the arrows in the photo:

[RELATED IMAGE OF KEYS USED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mttoF.jpg)

Has anyone had any success using this sketch or know where I'm going wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of several known problems with the firebase sketch.

The Firebase Registration ID is supposed to be different for every client app instance (not shared across apps or devices). You can dig up the one generated by an android session, but it's not straightforward. Better to get a new one by generating a key and requesting it.

The legacy API keys that you get from your console are long-lived but will only authorize requests to the legacy API.

The v1 API for HTTP uses a short-lived OAuth2.0 access token that's generated for a service account. to get this, you generate a private key from your firebase service account and then use that private key to request the access token that will be used in all subsequent message requests. When the token expires you'll get an updated one using the same private key.

You can read about this here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server

If you really want to re-use the reg ID it should be possible, though... try the sketch posted in FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino issue #250, which other have reported as working when the example sketch did not, with the same error you encountered. You can find that here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino/issues/250

Comment: Wow thank you so much I got it working by using the "dirty way" method in the #250 sketch. Thanks that's a massive help!!!